# show that k-√2 is irrational number

Tags: calculus

let k be rational number , show that k-√2 is irrational number

a rational number is any number that can be expressed as the quotient or fraction p/q of two integers, a numerator p and a non-zero denominator q

the irrational numbers are all the real numbers, which are not rational numbers,

could you please help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

SIOTDAC that $k-\sqrt2$  is rational. Then since $k$ is rational, let $k=p/q$ and say $k-\sqrt2 = a/b$. Then, by simple algebra:
$$p/q-\sqrt2 = a/b \Rightarrow bp - \sqrt2bq = aq \Rightarrow bp = q (a +\sqrt2b) \Rightarrow p/q - a/b = \sqrt2 \Rightarrow \sqrt2 = (pb-qa)/bq$$

which means that $\sqrt2$ is rational as it is expressible as a fraction. This is absurd.

(Even more simply, you could just move the $a/b$ to the other side of the equation and get the fraction).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two rational numbers is rational, viz. $a/b-c/d=(ad-bc)/bd$. Since $k$ is asked rational, if $k-\sqrt{2}$ were too then so would be $\sqrt{2}$, which it famously isn't.